# A question about the Cauchy criterion for infinite series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

This question is resolved. Thanks. I'm still working hard to improve my mathematical intuition.

Let $m$ be an integer and let $\sum_{n=m}^{\infty}a_n$ be an infinite series of real numbers.Then we have the Cauchy criterion:
$$
  \forall \varepsilon > 0:
  \exists M \geq m:
  \forall p, q \geq M:
  \left| \sum_{n=p}^{q} a_n \right| < \varepsilon \,.
$$
And I just found that there is another statement which is quite similar to the criterion above (but possibliy not equivalent):
$$
  \forall \varepsilon > 0:
  \exists M \geq m:
  \forall q \geq M:
  \left| \sum_{n=M}^{q} a_n \right| < \varepsilon \,.
$$
The second one is possibiliy wrong. Can anyone show an example of an infinite series $\sum_{n=m}^\infty a_n$ for which the second statement holds but which fails to be convergent?

Comment: What have you noticed? Is the second statement definitely no stronger than the first? Why would the first be called cauchy?

Comment: I have thought that the second one was no stronger than the first. Now I know that they are actually equivalent. The first one is called Cauchy in my book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both criteria are equivalent.
To go from the first criterion to the second criterion, we simply choose $p$ as $M$.
Suppose conversely that the series $\sum_{n = m}^∞ a_n$ satisfies the second criterion, and let $ε > 0$.
There exists by assumption some $M ≥ m$ such that $| \sum_{n = M}^q a_n | < ε/2$ for every $q ≥ M$.
It then follows for all $q ≥ p ≥ M$ that
$$
  \left| \sum_{n = p}^q a_n \right|
  = \left| \sum_{n = M}^q a_n - \sum_{n = M}^{p - 1} a_n \right|
  ≤ \left| \sum_{n = M}^q a_n \right| + \left| \sum_{n = M}^{p - 1} a_n \right|
  < \frac{ε}{2} + \frac{ε}{2}
  = ε \,.
$$

Comment: got it, and thanks a million!